# Emacs g++ [no match] when trying to use g++ on minibuffer

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, emacs, g++

I'm new to Emacs and just trying to write helloworld on Emacs but when I type `M-x g++` and `space` or `RTN` the minibuffer display `M-x g++ [No match]`. I had installed g++, gcc, gdb.

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
```

$PATH:

```
bash: /usr/bin/g++:/usr/bin/gcc:...
```

I also compiled hello.cpp:

```
Compilation started at Fri Sep 30 22:18:40  

make -k 
g++ -g -Wall -o hello hello.cpp   

Compilation finished at Fri Sep 30 22:18:40
```

Comment: `M-x` is for executing Emacs commands, not shell commands. Use `M-!` to execute a shell command from Emacs.

Comment: You can also create a buffer where you can type shell commands with `M-x shell`

Comment: That pretty fast!! Thank you and sorry for my noob question!!